# How to pass custom objects between activities?

Tags: java, android

I need to pass list of objects which contain fields such as Face(from Microsoft' Face client library) and Bitmap. I have read about Parcelable and Serializable but if I understood correctly, it doesn't allow for passing objects such as Face. Is this any possibility to do this?

Comment: Probably not. Either use a single activity and multiple fragments, or perhaps a Face should be something managed by a singleton repository object.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to pass data between activities is through `Intent` or `Bundles`, those objects can store objects that implemented `Parcelable` interface. As you are using, it seems to me, third-party objects, you must ensure that these objects implements the `Parcelable` or `Serializable` interfaces, otherwise, you can create a Face subclass and implements the required interfaces to pass through `Intents`, like:

```
MyFace face = ...;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(KEY_FACE, face);
```

And later, on the other Activity, you can get the extras from `getIntent()` Activity function.